# Crystal always printing portrait

Tags: c#-4.0, printing, crystal-reports, zebra-printers

I recently updated a Crystal Report from an unknown version to v13.  This report prints to a Zebra TLP2844 label printer using 6"x4" labels (6" long, 4" wide as they come out of the label printer).  Before the update, everything worked fine.  Afterwards, I cannot print the labels in landscape.  No matter what settings I use, I always get portrait.

Here are the settings I have in Visual Studio 2010:
[image]

My printing code:

```
 public void print_label(CTapeID myTape)
    {
        _myTape = myTape;
        LabelReport crystalPrint;  // name of report class
        CPrinterObject po;

        CPrinterInfo pi;
        String printerType = "LABEL_4060";
        LabelInfo cpd; // name of dataset class for the report

        try
        {
            crystalPrint = new LabelReport();

            crystalPrint.ReportOptions.EnableSaveDataWithReport = false;

            po = new CPrinterObject();
            pi = po.FindPrinter(printerType);

            if(pi != null)
            {
                crystalPrint.PrintOptions.PrinterName = pi.PrinterName;

            }

            crystalPrint.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation = CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperOrientation.Landscape;

            cpd = GetLabelData();
            crystalPrint.SetDataSource((DataSet)cpd);
            crystalPrint.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 1, 0);

            crystalPrint.Close();
            crystalPrint.Dispose();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.Source = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + "(): " + ex.Source;
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

`CPrinterObject` and `CPrinterInfo` are internal classes that get the printer name and properties.

Comment: Does it work if you manually print (i.e. using CR) the report in landscape mode?

Comment: @craig : If I go to Crystal Reports - Preview Report, I get the correct orientation.

Comment: But, what happens if you *actually* print it?  You want to make sure that you eliminate this potential point of error (the printer's driver).

Comment: Your code reads `crystalPrint.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation = CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperOrientation.Portrait;`.  Shouldn't this read `crystalPrint.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation = CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperOrientation.Landscape;`?

Comment: @craig Yup.  You're correct there.  I copy/pasted it from an old rev.  It does read '.Landscape' in the current code.  But it still prints out portrait.

Comment: Create a new report and see if you can print it in landscape mode.  This test would eliminate RPT corruption as an issue.

Comment: @craig Tried that.  Didn't work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31541/discussion-between-craig-and-curtishx)

Comment: @CurtisHx Did you resolve this issue? I have the same [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29800187/crystal-reports-prints-portrait-orientation-instead-of-landscape)

Comment: @Mariusz I did, however, I don't remember the exact solution to this.I think there was something embedded in the report that was forcing it to portrait.

Comment: That totally just got you a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

I just spent three and a half days tracking down this problem and reading zillions of old unanswered "I have this problem too. Did you ever solve it?" posts. I just finally cracked it.

No matter what code settings and paper sizes you choose, Crystal hates Zebra and will arbitrarily decide portrait/landscape, because it knows better than you.

What solved it for me was:

- Go into Print Management (not printer settings)
- Right-click on the printer
- Go to to "Set Printing Defaults"
- Set the paper size to something blatantly wrong (I said my 10cm x 2cm
  label was 10cm x  20cm), but big enough for it to STFU and stop
  choosing it for you.