# How to retrieve Crystal page setting programmatically in C#?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I created a Crystal report (.rpt file) in Crystal Designer. I configured Page Setup. I want to retrieve e.g. page orientation, page width, page high programmatically in C#. How to do it? Note that I want to retrieve page settings, no print settings. I don't want to edit page settings, I only need to read it.

**===EDIT===**

Following figure shows my page setup:

[image]

`PrintOptions.PageContentWidth` and `PrintOptions.PageContentHeight` in C# have different values.

```
ReportDocument rp = new ReportDocument();
rp.Load(path_to_my_report_file);
Console.WriteLine(rp.PrintOptions.PageContentHeight);
Console.WriteLine(rp.PrintOptions.PageContentWidth);
```

Output:

```
5670
8505
```

I need to retrieve page width and height to set they in PaperSize (`myPaperSize = new System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize(name, width, height);`)

Comment: I think the page settings and the print settings within the .rpt are the same thing, in which case you could find the info in `ReportDocument.PrintOptions`. Are you trying to find the page size with a user-defined size set?

Comment: @jjj I edited my question to show that `ReportDocument.PrintOptions` is different than my page setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ReportDocument.PrintOptions` should give you the numbers that you need. For example, for the page width, using members of `PrintOptions`:

```
PageContentWidth + PageMargins.leftMargin + PageMargins.rightMargin
```

*However*, these values are in [TWIPS](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3380601), where **1440 twips = 1 inch**. (I have no idea what the proper capitalization is...)

---

On the other hand, `System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize` uses numbers in hundredths of an inch, so you would have to convert:

```
[Dimension in hundredths of an inch] = [Dimension in TWIPS] / 1440.0 * 100
```

Comment: @Mariusz: I'm getting `15 cm = 8504 twips` and `10 cm = 5669 twips`, not sure why it's off by one.

Comment: Thank you very much for help. Do you know how to retrieve page orientation? `rp.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation` always returns portrait. I think that comparing of width and height is not sufficient to get page orientation.

Comment: If `PrintOptions.PaperOrientation` doesn't work, and checking `PageContentWidth > PageContentHeight` (with or without margins) doesn't work, I guess I'm not sure what else would.